# How to test if users remain consistent in their preferences?

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I am unable to find a suitable way to statistically test the hypothesis that users remain consistent over time in their preference for various product attributes. The three product attributes whose relative importance are rated includes quality, cost, and aesthetics.

The data consists of rows with individual id, product id, importance of quality, importance of cost, importance of aesthetics.

Individual and product ids are unique identifiers. The importance scores sum up to 100. Here is how a snapshot of the data looks.

| user_id | product_id | quality | cost | aesthetics |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| u1 | p1 | 50 | 20 | 30 |
| u1 | p3 | 40 | 30 | 30 |
| u1 | p4 | 40 | 40 | 20 |
| u2 | p1 | 20 | 30 | 40 |
| u2 | p5 | 30 | 40 | 30 |
| u3 | p1 | 35 | 35 | 30 |
| u300 | p2 | 40 | 40 | 20 |
| u300 | p3 | 15 | 15 | 70 |

Are there any significance tests for the hypothesis that users generally remain consistent in their preferences for quality, cost, and aesthetics?

Any way to do this in R?

Comment: Is [tag:consistency] the relevant tag here?

Comment: How many users? How many products? To check consistency over time I suppose you also have a column for time/date ... maybe start with visualization, ternary plots could be useful, see examples in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275039/ternary-diagrams-in-scatter-plot-matrix-pairs-with-r-compositions  Could you share (some part of) your data?